# I'm starting to learn T-SQL and I had a problem creating a foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm starting to learn T-SQL and experimenting with creating a basic database and setting up some relationships between tables. This is the code I'm using:

```
CREATE DATABASE Colegio
ON PRIMARY
(NAME = ColegioPrimary, Filename = 'C:\Datos\ColegioPrimary.mdf',
size = 500MB, filegrowth = 75%)
LOG ON
(NAME = ColegioLog, Filename = 'C:\Datos\ColegioLog.ldf',
size = 100MB, filegrowth = 25%)
go

ALTER DATABASE Colegio
ADD FILEGROUP Produccion
go

ALTER DATABASE Colegio
ADD FILE (NAME = ColegioProduccion, Filename = 'C:\Datos\ColegioProduccion.ndf',
size = 50MB, filegrowth = 25%) TO FILEGROUP Produccion
go

ALTER DATABASE Colegio
MODIFY filegroup[Produccion] DEFAULT
go

create table Estudiante
(
    EstudianteID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Nombre nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Apellido nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Edad int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_EstudianteID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(EstudianteID),
    CONSTRAINT CK_Edad CHECK(Edad >=3),
    ProfesorID int
)
GO

create table Profesor
(
    ProfesorID int identity(1,1) not null,
    Nombre nvarchar(20) not null,
    apellido nvarchar(20) not null,
    profesion varchar(30) not null,
    edad int not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ProfesorID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ProfesorID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Profesor_Estudiante FOREIGN KEY(EstudianteID) -- right here is the problem
    references dbo.Estudiante(EstudianteID) on update cascade,
    constraint ck_edad check(edad >=20)
)
go
```

An error is thrown in trying to create the foreign key in the 'Profesor' table, as indicated above. Could someone explain why an error is being thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the foreign key constraint, you need to reference a column that exists in your current table as well as the column in the table you're linking it to. In the line you've indicated above, you're attempting to create a foreign key constraint on the column 'EstudianteID', which exists only in the Estudiante table. You need an integer column in the 'Profesor' table that can hold the foreign key values.

For your CREATE on the 'Profesor' table, you'll want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Profesor
(
    ProfesorID int identity(1,1) not null,
    EstudianteID int not null, --Adding this line here
    Nombre nvarchar(20) not null,
    apellido nvarchar(20) not null,
    profesion varchar(30) not null,
    edad int not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ProfesorID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ProfesorID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Profesor_Estudiante FOREIGN KEY(EstudianteID) references dbo.Estudiante(EstudianteID) on update cascade,
    constraint ck_edad check(edad >=20)
)
go
```

Comment: This is my first time using the website, thank you for your help